# Not all attributes of CSS style class are applied

Tags: html, css

I have following written in a CSS file.

```
span.hoverhelp
{
    border:double;
    border-width:3;
    border-color:#000000;
    background-color:#eeffcc;
    padding:5;
    font-size: 11;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80;
    left: 170;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now, I am creating a span and applying the class hoverhelp to it. Following is the tag:

```
<span id="help" class="hoverhelp">
Some text
</span>
```

When this gets rendered then, border-width, padding, font-size, top and left styles do not get applied. When opened in chrome dev toolbar, these values are stroke through and a small yellow warning triangle appears on the left side saying 'Invalid property value.'

I might be making a silly mistake. Can anyone notice any pitfall here?

Comment: You must put a unit after values of these attributes border-width,  padding, font-size, top, left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS lengths require units. You probably want `px` for most of them.

Use [a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: bang on! I added the units and it worked like a charm! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add units (exception: 0 it's 0).

You can choise between:

- %    percentage
- in   inch
- cm   centimeter
- mm   millimeter
- em   1em is equal to the current font size.
- ex   one ex is the x-height of a font
- pt   point (1 pt is the same as 1/72 inch)
- pc   pica (1 pc is the same as 12 points)
- px   pixels (a dot on the computer screen)

Answer (score 0):

remove `visibility: hidden;` from the CSS and also add px for most of them.

Answer (score 0):

you miss `px` at many place try using this code.

```
span.hoverhelp
{
    border:double;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:#000000;
    background-color:#eeffcc;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 170px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

see css validation service : [<kbd>LINK</kbd>](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Answer (score 0):

those values that are not being applied need to be in px or em.
So, basically,

```
border-width:3px;
padding:5px;
font-size: 11px;
```

Answer (score 0):

just "border" wont do it has to be "border-style", so following will do

```
span.hoverhelp
{
    border-style:double;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:#000000;
    background-color:#eeffcc;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 170px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

but as you making it invisible by default, it wont be seen. You've to have a parent element with relative position & on hover of the same this span would appear.